# How to put QWidget on a middle in not dependence on screen sizes in Pyside2 using the program Qt Designer?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2

I use Pyside2 now>Qt Desiger And I want by sight to influence the reflection of the program.

Before to translate him with ui on py  and to edit him in a text editor
And wanted to know whether it is possible inwardly Qt Desiger to put QWidget exactly on the middle of screen without depending on his size.
Only where I found and able to use a code this stylesheet and that not all commands from css he accepts.

I do not want while to use a command line because for me uncomfortably enough constantly to change a small detail and restart a code 
what to understand as she was represented In the beginning I would like to create a template on Qt Designer and then already edit it in a command line If it is possible how to edit that not closing the code Qt Designer that I would like to know how to do it

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc I need an answer for PySide2 but not for QT.I want by sight to change the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no answer for python I have published this answer which is a translation of [the official example of Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Center_a_Window_on_the_Screen).

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.resize(640, 480)

    w.setGeometry(
        QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
            QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight,
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter,
            w.size(),
            QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().primaryScreen().availableGeometry()
            # or
            # QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().desktop().availableGeometry(),
        )
    )
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

You can set the stretch in the QGridLayout to the first and third column, similar to the rows:

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" rowstretch="1,0,1" columnstretch="1,0,1">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>142</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>254</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(239, 41, 41);</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>21</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Text</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>254</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>141</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: @orlatym If you want more help you must provide a [MRE]

Comment: How can I give the example yet not translated file of ui?
https://habrastorage.org/webt/5e/16/1d/5e161d6dbd201240690808.png

Comment: @orlatym Now I understand your question better since in your question you are using incorrect terms, for example you use the term screen instead of window, screen is the element part of your device instead window is referring to one of the toplevels of your widgets